# LibGDX Desktop flicker

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop, flicker

This question has been posted before, but i have problems with flickering sprites in libGdx.
I have looked everywhere on stackoverflow, google, etc but nothing helped me.

The sprites only flicker when they move. It flickers less when i move them slower, but it flickers a lot when a little bit faster. This is very annoying and ofcourse unplayable.

This is my code:

```
package com.wouter.DuelArena;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import ...

public class DuelArena extends Game {

Sprite player;
float playerX;
float playerY;

boolean fireBool;
Sprite fireSprite;
Texture fireText;

OrthographicCamera cam;

Texture playerTexture;
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create() {      
    fireBool = false;
    fireText = new Texture("data/droplet.png");
    fireText.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    fireSprite = new Sprite(fireText);

    playerTexture = new Texture("data/bucket.png");
    playerTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    player = new Sprite(playerTexture);     
    player.setSize(70, 128);
    playerX = 0f;
    playerY = 0f;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,  1,  1,  1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();


    player.draw(batch);
    input();
    update();

    batch.end();

    super.render();
}
private void update()
{
    player.setPosition(playerX, playerY);

    if (fireBool)
    {
        fireSprite.setX(fireSprite.getX() + 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        fireSprite.draw(batch);

        if (fireSprite.getX() > 1280)
            fireBool = false;
    }
}
private void input()
{
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && player.getX() > 0)
    {
        playerX -= 200f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) && player.getX() < 1280)
    {
        playerX += 200f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) && !fireBool)
    {
        fireBool = true;
        fireSprite.setPosition(playerX, playerY + 35f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();
}
```

}

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I'm not sure it could cause this, but you should remove the `super.render();`

Comment: But you're most probably right! I read in a tutorial you can't delete the super.render, but that was when our renderfunction was empty! So what i do is a double render, which means my screen is cleared twice! Thanks a lot! You made my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the position of the call to the super.render:

```
super.render();
```

In a [Game](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html) class, the super.render needs to be the first line in the code, not the last, like this:

```
@Override
public void render(){
    super.render(); //<-----

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,  1,  1,  1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    player.draw(batch);
    input();
    update();
    batch.end();
}
```

It is actually very important to put it there if you override the render method in Game, because thats the one that calls the render of the current [Screen](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html). You aren't using Screens in this example, but if you are using Game you probably should (will :p).